# Are the terms formula and algorithm synonymous in formal logic?

Tags: terminology, formal-theory

How to do something in two or more steps would feel/grasped to me as pretty much matching the common usages of both terms, but to find possible nuances common in the philosophical literature in general (and the formal logic literature in particular) I ask this question.

Comment: No; see [Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm): "in mathematics and computer science, an algorithm is a finite sequence of well-defined instructions, typically used to solve a class of specific problems or to perform a computation."